# How return leaf nodes of a boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I have a property tree where all the data is stored in its leaf nodes. The Tree, however, has a complex structure. What I want to do now is:

1. get all (and only the) leaf nodes of the tree, for they contain the data and
2. recall the path leading to the respective leaf node

Eventually, I want to receive a key/value pair of all (and only the) leaf nodes where the key contains the complete path to the node and the value contains the node's value.

My questions are:

1. Is there a more convenient way than to recursively iterate through the whole tree, store the respective path and read out the values of the nodes that don't have children (i.e. a "*get_leaves()*" function)?
2. If I have some pointer to a subtree (*ptree* variable, *iterator*, whatever..) of a given tree, is there a method to easily determine the relative path of that subtree inside the tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just write some helper functions. They're really not that difficult. Here's a completely generic tree visitation function that optionally takes a predicate:

```
template <typename Tree, typename F, typename Pred/* = bool(*)(Tree const&)*/, typename PathType = std::string>
void visit_if(Tree& tree, F const& f, Pred const& p, PathType const& path = PathType())
{
    if (p(tree))
        f(path, tree);

    for(auto& child : tree)
        if (path.empty())
            visit_if(child.second, f, p, child.first);
        else
            visit_if(child.second, f, p, path + "." + child.first);
}

template <typename Tree, typename F, typename PathType = std::string>
void visit(Tree& tree, F const& f, PathType const& path = PathType())
{
    visit_if(tree, f, [](Tree const&){ return true; }, path);
}
```

You can use it with a predicate like

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

bool is_leaf(boost::property_tree::ptree const& pt) {
    return pt.empty();
}
```

And here's a simple demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc9245a11ed036c1)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    auto process = [](ptree::path_type const& path, ptree const& node) {
            std::cout << "leave node at '" << path.dump() << "' has value '" << node.get_value("") << "'\n";
        };

    ptree pt;
    pt.put("some.deeply.nested.values", "just");
    pt.put("for.the.sake.of.demonstration", 42);

    visit_if(pt, process, is_leaf);
}
```

Prints:

```
leave node at 'some.deeply.nested.values' has value 'just'
leave node at 'for.the.sake.of.demonstration' has value '42'
```

**UPDATE**

Just noted the second half of the question. here's how to do it using the same visitor:

```
template <typename Tree>
boost::optional<std::string> path_of_optional(Tree const& tree, Tree const& target) {
    boost::optional<std::string> result;

    visit(tree, [&](std::string const& path, Tree const& current) { if (&target == &current) result = path; });

    return result;
}

template <typename Tree>
std::string path_of(Tree const& tree, Tree const& target) {
    auto r = path_of_optional(tree, target);
    if (!r) throw std::range_error("path_of");
    return *r;
}
```

And a demo **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60415b2cd6365329)**

```
std::cout << "Path from node: " << path_of(pt, pt.get_child("for.the.sake")) << "\n";
```

Comment: Added a `path_of[_optional]` implementation in the update: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60415b2cd6365329)

Comment: Although it's still iterating through (unfortunately there seems to be no other way), your implementation is absolutely great and elegant. Thanks a lot!